# Onclick for sqlite in listview?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I've created this code that populate SQLite in Listview, but what I'm struggeling in is that I want to show TOAST message depending on what user chooses from the listview.Should I go with onClick method?.

```
    public void createTable(SQLiteDatabase mDb, String table) {
        try {
            mDb.execSQL("create table if not exists "
                    + table
                    + " (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + "username text not null, birthday text not null,image text);");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yes",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void insert(SQLiteDatabase mDb, String table) {

                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();


    public void getAllData(String table) {
        Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("select * from " + table, null);
        int columnsSize = c.getColumnCount();
        listData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            for (int i = 0; i < columnsSize; i++) {
                map.put("id", c.getString(0));
                map.put("username", c.getString(1));
                map.put("birthday", c.getString(2));
                map.put("image", c.getString(3));
            }
            listData.add(map);
        }           
    }
    public boolean delete(SQLiteDatabase mDb, String table, int id) {
        String whereClause = "id=?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(id) };
        try {
            mDb.delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "هˆ é™¤و•°وچ®ه؛“ه¤±è´¥",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

OnCreateContextMenuListener listviewLongPress = new OnCreateContextMenuListener(){
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        final AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =
        (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ListView_SqliteActivity.this)
                .setTitle("عنوان1")
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setMessage("عنوان 2")
                .setPositiveButton("وک¯",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(
                                    DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
                                int mListPos = info.position;
                                HashMap<String, Object> map = listData
                                        .get(mListPos);
                                int id = Integer.valueOf((map.get("id")
                                        .toString()));
                                if (dao.delete(mDb, "student", id)) {                                       
                                    listData.remove(mListPos);
                                    listItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("هگ¦",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(
                                    DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {

                            }
                        }).show();
    }
};

@Override
public void finish() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.finish();
    mDb.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume little from your question that you want to implement Click event for the ListView, and you want to display Toast Message for the click.

So, implement **`setOnItemClickListener`** for your listview to handle list item click.

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
           // do whatever you want
        }
    });
```

Comment: where should I paste this ? can you tell me please?

Comment: After this line: `list.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(listviewLongPress);`